# PIg scalar is bigger than 0

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera, scalar

I have the following code

```
Data1 = LOAD '/user/cloudera/Class Ex 2/Data 1' USING PigStorage(',') as (Name:chararray,ID:chararray,text_1:chararray,Grade_1:int,Grade_2:int,Grade_3:int,Grade_4:int);
Data2 = LOAD '/user/cloudera/Class Ex 2/Data 2' USING PigStorage(',') as (Name:chararray,ID:chararray,text_2:chararray,Grade_5:int,Grade_6:int,Grade_7:int,Grade_8:int);

Data_3 = JOIN Data1 BY Data1.ID,Data2 BY Data2.ID;
Data_4 = FOREACH Data_3 GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13;

Data_5 = FOREACH Data_4 GENERATE
                            Name,
                            ID,
                            text_1,
                            SIZE(text_1),
                            REPLACE(text_1,'or',''),
                            SIZE(REPLACE(text_1,'or','')),
                            SIZE(text_1)-SIZE(REPLACE(text_1,'or','')),
                            text_2,
                            SIZE(text_2),
                            REPLACE(text_2,'or',''),
                            SIZE(REPLACE(text_2,'or','')),
                            SIZE(text_2)-SIZE(REPLACE(text_2,'or','')),
                            ($3+$4+$5+$6+$8+$9+$10+$11)/8;
DESCRIBE Data_5;
STORE Data_5 Into '/user/cloudera/Class Ex 2/Data_output' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Essentially I have to load 2 sets of data, and then make some basic text statistics and manipulation.
Everything works fine until the last statement, STORE.
When I add it I receive the scalar error.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Pig only evaluates the alias' which finally lead to a `STORE` or a `DUMP` (this is called lazy evaluation). Hence, your error was always there; It just got caught once you added the `STORE` statement. Since you have not pasted the full trace, I would think that your error is in the third statement where you try to access the field `ID` using the dot (`.`) operator. You need to change it to one of the following:

1) Refer to the field `ID` directly since only one field called `ID` in both `Data1` and `Data2`:

```
Data_3 = JOIN Data1 BY ID, Data2 BY ID;
```

2) Use `::` instead of `.` if you do need to disambiguate:

```
Data_3 = JOIN Data1 BY Data1::ID, Data2 BY Data2::ID;
```

If you want to know why the dot (`.`) operator caused an error, might help to look at the following question: [Getting exception while trying to execute a Pig Latin Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466235/getting-exception-while-trying-to-execute-a-pig-latin-script/51467598#51467598)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried the :: operator instead of the dot, but I recived the following error :
2018-11-23 10:14:55,015 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1025: 
<file pig-02f6.pig, line 4, column 23> Invalid field projection. Projected field [Data1::ID] does not exist in schema: Name:chararray,ID:chararray,text_1:chararray,Grade_1:int,Grade_2:int,Grade_3:int,Grade_4:int.

I still don't have a clue what is wrong here.

Comment: Since you do no need to disambiguate, the first option (direct reference) in the answer should work fine. The `::` operator is generally needed after a `JOIN` (for example) where the relations being joined have fields with the same name, hence needing a way to disambiguate them.